# Create variables from a JavaScript array of filenames

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I have a JavaScript array with the filenames (and their directory location) in it (originally gotten by using PHP to create a PHP array of files in the directory and then converted to a JS array). I'd like to use this array to generate individual variables with the same name as their value.

For example, this is one of the array values, "collada/basement/zones/basementPCroom.dae". I'd like to use this to create a variable called "basementPCroom" which holds the value "collada/basement/zones/basementPCroom.dae". And the same with all other values in the array.

The reason I want to do this is because changing each individually every time I add or remove files would take forever, and I need them to have those specific names so that I can find what I'm looking for easily later.

Thanks for your help!

Below is the code leading up to this:

```
<?php
$zones = glob('collada/first/zones/*dae');
?>
var zones = <?php echo json_encode($zones) ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to do it like this (there might be more optimum ways to do this):

```
var filenames = filenames || {};

for(var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
   filenames[getName(array[i])] = array[i];
}

function getName(str) {
   var parts = str.split('/');
   return parts[parts.length-1].split('.')[0];
 }
```

**Update:** Merged my updates to create a object to hold fielnames instead of polluting global namesapce.

Comment: Polluting the global namespace is totally not the way to go about it.

Comment: Agree with Shef, even if the OP seemed to ask for globals.  Also the OP wants the path and extensions stripped.  Try building a new object whose properties (keys) and the base filenames, and check for errors. :-)

Comment: @Shef @Ray Toal @Mrchief I've updated the question so that you know what I'm talking about better.

Comment: @Mrchief
Thanks for that. I'm trying to incorporate it. But my JavaScript skills are pretty bad, I'm new to it. Could you explain what's happening and show me how to incorporate it with what I've shown above and maybe print out the variables' names and values so I know it's working. Sorry, i know it's asking a lot, but I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: You can run the `for` loop in any `function` you want. After its done, you can access individual filenames like this: `filenames.basementPCroom`. Do an `alert(filenames.basementPCroom);` to see its value. IF you're on FF, you can also use `console.log(filenames.basementPCroom)` to log its values to debug console and validate.

Comment: @Mrchief Cheers. Can you explain to me what the 3 individual parts above actually do please?

Comment: Well, the first one contains an array of all individual parts: `collada, basement, zones, basementPCroom.dae`. I access the filename (last item in array) by doing `array.length - 1` and then split again to create an array with `filename, extension`. Then I return the first array item to get the filename. You can also get the filename by using  `string.substring` but array split felt easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do the work server-side you could do something like this:

```
$zoneArray = glob('whatever');

//grab keys
$grabFileName = function($val){
   return substring($val, strrchar($val, '/'), strchar($val, '.'));
}
$zoneKeys = array_map($grabFileName, $zoneArray);

//apply keys to array
$zoneHash = array_combine($zoneKeys, $zoneArray);

//associative arrays become objects
json_encode($zoneHash);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to "create variables". Instead put everything in an object, aka associative array:

```
var paths = {};
paths[a_file_name] = its_directory;
```

This uses the fact that you can use bracket notation instead of dot notation to acess an object in Javascript

```
obj['foo']
//is the same as
obj.foo
```